# EF Core DbCommand duration vs CommandTimeout

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have to investigate a performance issue with SQL Server and EF Core and I noticed something strange in the log:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (300,021ms) [Parameters=[...], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300']
Failed executing DbCommand (600,027ms) [Parameters=[...], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='600']
```

From what I know the `CommandTimeout` is measured in seconds but the `DbCommand` says it took the same amount in milliseconds.

What does `DbCommand` measure in fact? Was the same amount in milliseconds a coincidence with the same amount in seconds (I saw on the internet the same exception of timeout but the duration was different than command timeout even smaller actually)?

PS: I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further looking at the time it seems that the values was written with thousand separator and since I was looking on a German machine though that the values was 300 but in fact it was 300000ms which is indeed 30 seconds. Looks like the time was correct